# sort list of floating-point numbers in groups

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of floating-point numbers, which is unordered. I know that the values always fall around a few points, which are not known. For illustration, this list

```
[10.01,5.001,4.89,5.1,9.9,10.1,5.05,4.99]
```

has values clustered around 5 and 10, so I would like [5,10] as answer.

I would like to find those clusters for lists with 1000+ values, where the nunber of clusters is probably around 10 (for some given tolerance). How to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check [python-cluster](https://pypi.org/project/cluster/). With this library you could do something like this :

```
from cluster import *

data = [10.01,5.001,4.89,5.1,9.9,10.1,5.05,4.99]
cl = HierarchicalClustering(data, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
print [mean(cluster) for cluster in cl.getlevel(1.0)]
```

And you would get:

```
[5.0062, 10.003333333333332]
```

(This is a very silly example, because I don't really know what you want to do, and because this is the first time I've used this library)

Comment: A short usage example would be nice. That link might be outdated soon.

Comment: The documentation of the package is all I needed to use it, and it works just great.

Comment: For the real problem, you may want to use a least-squares distance function: `lambda x,y: (x-y)**2`.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the following method:

Sort the array first, and use diff() to calculate the difference between two continuous values. the difference larger than threshold can be consider as the split position:

```
import numpy as np
x = [10.01,5.001,4.89,5.1,9.9,10.1,5.05,4.99]
x = np.sort(x)
th = 0.5
print [group.mean() for group in np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) > th)[0]+1)]
```

the result is:

```
[5.0061999999999998, 10.003333333333332]
```