# Python: Uniquefying a list with a twist

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list:

```
L = [15,16,57,59,14]
```

The list contains mesurements, that are not very accurate: that is the real value of an element is +-2 of the recorded value. So 14,15 and 16 can have the same value. What I want to do is to uniquefy that list, taking into account the mesurement errors. The output should therefor be:

```
l_out = [15,57]
```

or

```
l_out = [(14,15,16),(57,59)]
```

I have no problem producing either result with a for loop. However, I am curious if there could be a more elegant solution. Ideas much appriciated.

Comment: What result do you expect for `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]`?

Comment: And what would be the output of [15,16,57,59,14,13]?

Comment: I am aware of the problem, but the data that I have in mind is groped so that the distance between groups is >2

Comment: @kosii, in that case it should again have the values in two groups. that is 15+-2.

Comment: +1 for question title (oh and great question)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8226923/566644) question and its answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As lazyr pointed out in the comments, a similar problem has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226923/sort-list-of-floating-point-numbers-in-groups). Using the cluster module the solution to my problem would be:

```
>>> from cluster import *
>>> L = [15,16,57,59,14]
>>> cl = HierarchicalClustering(L, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
>>> cl.getlevel(2)
[[14, 15, 16], [57, 59]]
```

or (to get unique list with mean values of each group):

```
>>> [mean(cluster) for cluster in cl.getlevel(2)]
[15, 58]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want standard lib python, `itertool`'s `groupby` is your friend:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [15,16,57,59,14]

# Stash state outside key function. (a little hacky).
# Better way would be to create stateful class with a __call__ key fn.
state = {'group': 0, 'prev': None}
thresh = 2

def _group(cur):
    """Group if within threshold."""
    if state["prev"] is not None and abs(state["prev"] - cur) > thresh:
        state["group"] += 1 # Advance group
    state["prev"] = cur
    return state["group"]

# Group, then drop the group key and inflate the final tuples.
l_out = [tuple(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(L), key=_group)]

print l_out
# -> [(14, 15, 16), (57, 59)]
```

Comment: I think you could avoid the global state by grouping the values into pairs first via `l = sorted(L); zip(l, l[1:])`

Comment: @NiklasB. -- yep! The other way would be a more classical decorate-sort-undecorate pattern... Or I guess sort-decorate-group-undecorate ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do this in a pure-Python approach:

```
s = sorted(L)
b = [i + 1 for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(s, s[1:])) if y > x + 2]
result = [s[i:j] for i, j in zip([None] + b, b + [None])]
```

Here `b` is the list of "breaks", indices where a cluster ends.

Answer (score -1):

For loop is the simplest way, but if you really want a single-line code:
`l_out = list(set(tuple([tuple(filter(lambda i: abs(item - i) < 3, L)) for item in L])))`
Very unclear though, I would prefer the for version :)

Comment: he said "I am aware of the problem, but the data that I have in mind is groped so that the distance between groups is >2"

Comment: that condition is fulfilled here. still your program doesn't partition the list properly.